# Topographic map in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I want to make a recursive code to give multiple elipses with different colors like a topographic map of a mountain, like in Mathematica I would have this image when typing: ContourPlot[(x/5)² + (y/3)², {x, −6, 6}, {y, −6, 6}, Contours → 15]

[image]

But I can't find how to make it in a smart way. I know how to make the elipses colored, but I don't want to draw every single one, I'd like to put the equation and have it giving to me the graphic like this.

I tried using "foreach" in Tikz, but honestly I don't think I get it how the loop works, 'cause it doesn't compile. Tried using "radial shading" but don't know how to make it a elipse (not a circle) and it also needs me to input the values, and I don't wish to make every single one.

I was wondering if maybe there is a way to write something like (x/5)² + (y/3)²=k, where the k's closer to (0,0) would be blue and the further orange. The distante between the elipses in x is 0.34, so I thought maybe a recursion could solve that, 'cause I'd need only to write the first one, and the next would be 0.34 greater in x and in y would be proportional.

But I'm accepting any sugestions to solve this.

I was trying this (but it doesn't work), if it helps:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-6, xmax=6,
            ymin=-6, ymax=6,
            xtick={-6,-4,...,6},
            ytick={-6,-4,...,6},
            %grid=major,
        ]
            
            \foreach \x in {1.5,1.84,...,6.6}
            \foreach \k in {1,2,...,15}
                \draw[] (0,0) ellipse [
                x radius =\x,
                y radius = \sqrt{3*\k - 0.6*\x^2 },
                ]; 
                
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I don't see where a *recursive code* would be involved in that. This seems to be reachable with a simple `foreach` loop. Please provide some informations about how you want the ellipses to be drawn so that we could help you out. And be welcomed to TeX-SE.

Comment: I thought abou recursion because the distance in x between the elipses is 0.34, so I thought maybe I could describe the equation for the first one (in the middle) and the others be written related to the last one. But if you have a better idea, please say, I'm new to all that.

Comment: Perhaps `pgfplots` package (`contour` graphics) can help you.

Comment: I was using it, I tried to look at the manual, I think gnuplot was what reach the closest to what I want, but it's the first time I've used this, so to be honest it's a bit confusing to me. I know how to draw elipses, and how to use color scales, but I didn't find an example similar to what I'm searching to try and figure it out how to make them both work together in a smart way.

Comment: Well, You could put a minimum work example, part or all the necessary code with which you obtain the figure above. Also you can try with `contour lua` option if you can't get `gnuplot`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial solution out of may approaches, to give some direction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        % shading the biggest ellipse
        \fill [outer color=orange!50, inner color=blue!80] (0,0)   
                circle [x radius=5 * 0.2 cm, y radius=5 * 0.333 cm];
        
        % drawing some ellipses without fills
        \foreach \r in {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}{
            \draw (0,0)   circle [x radius=\r * 0.2 cm, y radius=\r * 0.333 cm];        
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Approach and remarks**:

1. Draw the biggest ellipse first, with a varying shading. `orange!50` means some kind of highlighting. Chose better colors ;-)
2. Draw open ellipses over that shaded area. You only need to change the radius. Adjust the foreach loop as needed. With your parameters given, the x-axis is narrower ...
3. I used opening and closing `{}` inside the loop. For this one-liner braces are not needed, but will be useful, if you perform more actions within the loop.
4. My approach was bottom-up, or Test-Driven-Design (TDD) if you will, i.e. drawing 1 open ellipse first, drawing more than 1, introducing shading ... which leaves some residuals. I.e. the arguments for the x radius and y radius should be generalized etc.

**To be done:**

- introduce clipping
- introduce grid or axis

**Result**:

[image: Result]

**P.S.**: If you want to calculate each point of the ellipses yourself and display it, check out `\datavisualizaton` in chapter "Ticks and Grids" of the big pgf manual.

Comment: That helped a lot, but it has the same problem that "shade" has. I don't know how to "frame" it with the grid and make it keep being an elipse. Like when I write 

\shadedraw[inner color=yellow,outer color=black,draw=yellow] (6,0) rectangle +(2,1);

Ok, that's a rectangle with an elipse and it has a gradient, but as soon as I extend the rectangle to become a square the elipse becomes a circle and I don't know how to move with this parameters. Does that make sense?

Comment: @CoraSanroman, the concept is clipping. I.e. you draw too big, and cut away, so to say, what is outside the rectangle you define. It's a diffrenet way of thinking and drawing. // There are at least two shading algorithms: one, that fills a rectangle and mimicks some eliptic apperance, and the second I used: shading a distorted circle, i.e. an ellipse. / You could also draw \fill-circles on each other for a course gradient.  // What helped me was to skim through the introductory parts of relevant chapters in the pgf manual, to grasp the various concepts. Digging from there yields quick results.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a starting point for how to draw multiple ellipses without having to plot any function, here's a way to approach it (which is neither perfect nor close enough, in my opinion, to what you asked for):

[image: foreach ellipses]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \definecolor{innercol}{RGB}{51, 102, 153}
        \definecolor{outercol}{RGB}{255, 204, 102}
        \def\R{5} \def\r{3}
        
        \begin{scope}           
            \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
            \foreach \i in {1,...,20}
                {
                \pgfmathsetmacro\x{\R/(0.45*1.05^(\i))}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\y{\r/(0.45*1.05^(\i))}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\col{\i*5}
                \draw[very thin,fill=innercol!\col!outercol] (0,0) ellipse (\x cm and \y cm);
                }
            \draw[help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);           
        \end{scope}
        
        \foreach \x in {-5,-4,...,5} \draw (\x,-5) --++ (0,-3pt) node[below] {\small \x};
        \foreach \y in {-5,-4,...,5} \draw (-5,\y) --++ (-3pt,0) node[left] {\small \y};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You may be able to play with how the radii are computed to change the aspect of the ellipses, and maybe create a more complex colour shading.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I'm gonna work with that, if I get what I want I'll share with you. ♥